# Traceback Error When I Run My Python Code

Tags: python-3.x

I get a Traceback Error, when I run my Python Code, in Jupyter Notebook, and I am not sure, what is causing the Traceback Errors. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import target
import pip_api
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("http://web.archive.org/web/20070826230746/http://www.bbmf.co.uk/july07.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

df = pd.read_html(str(table))
df = df[1]
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0])
df = df.iloc[2:]
df.head(15)

Southport = df[
    (
        df['Location'].str.contains('- Display') & 
        df['Lancaster'] == '' & 
        df['Dakota'] == 'D' & 
        df['Spitfire'] == 'S' & 
        df['Hurricane'] == 'H'
    )
] | df[
    (
        df['Location'].str.contains('- Display') & 
        df['Lancaster'] == '' & 
        df['Dakota'] == 'D' & 
        df['Spitfire'] == 'S' &
        df['Hurricane'] == ''
    )
] | df[
    (
        df['Location'].str.contains('- Display') & 
        df['Lancaster'] == '' & 
        df['Dakota'] == 'D' & 
        df['Spitfire'] == 'SS' &
        df['Hurricane'] == ''
    )
]
```

And Here is part, of the Traceback Error, Any Ideas ? :-

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-5ec7c798b521> in <module>
         38             df['Hurricane'] == ''
         39         )
    ---> 40     ] | df[
         41         (
         42             df['Location'].str.contains('- Display') &

    c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in wrapper(self, other)
       1848         filler = (fill_int if is_self_int_dtype and   is_other_int_dtype
       1849                   else fill_bool)
    -> 1850         res_values = na_op(self.values, ovalues)
       1851         unfilled = self._constructor(res_values,
       1852                                      index=self.index,  name=res_name)

    c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
       1808                                     "with a scalar of type   [{typ}]"
       1809                                     .format(dtype=x.dtype,
    -> 1810                                              typ=type(y).__name__))
       1811 
       1812         return result
```

Comment: You've added the traceback, but it appears you have chopped off the actual error in the process. Could you add it back?

Answer (score 0):

You need more parentheses, around the individual comparisons:

```
((df['Location'].str.contains('- Display')) &
 (df['Lancaster'] == '') &
 (df['Dakota'] == 'D') &
 (df['Spitfire'] == 'S') &
 (df['Hurricane'] == 'H'))
```

Otherwise, `&` binds with the object before the next equal sign `==`, instead of the result of the next comparison.

Comment: Many thanks, for helping me out, I now get the following short Traceback Error :- <code>File "<ipython-input-3-6d53e7e5ec10>", line 31
    )
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

</code>

Comment: @EdwardWinch One question at a time, please. If you have other problems, please ask a new question.

Comment: OK will do, just give me a minute. Eddie

Comment: It says I can only post every 90 minutes, so will post the latest Thread when I can. Regards  Eddie